# Running powershell script with AHK hotkey doesn nothing. PS script in itself works

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

As title, I have to two powershell scripts to change mouse speed. They work, if I run them through powershell, but if I try to assign AHK shortcuts to them the PS window pops up and the mouse speed remains unchanged.

AHK:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
+Esc::Reload  ; Shift+Esc

!1:: ; Alt+1, slow
Run "%A_ScriptDir%\mouse_slow.ps1"
Return

!2:: ; Alt+2, fast
Run "%A_ScriptDir%\mouse_default.ps1"
Return
```

Powershell:

```
param([Int32]$Speed = 10)

$MethodDefinition = @" 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")] 
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni); 
"@ 

$User32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name "User32Set" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$User32::SystemParametersInfo(0x0071, 0, $Speed, 0) | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse" -Name MouseSensitivity -Value $Speed
```

Comment: When you "run them through Powershell", how do you do it ? Vscode / ISE or something else ? If the former, it might be an execution policy issue... Is your script policy for powershell unrestricted ? `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. If not unrestricted, you need to set it so or use the  `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` argument in your `Run` command (I don't use AHK but the non AHK equivalenet would be `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .runme.ps1`

Comment: Double click in file explorer  on the ps1 file :) Vscode + powershell doesn't play nice on my work laptop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
+Esc::Reload  ; Shift+Esc

!1:: ; Alt+1, slow
Run, powershell  -noLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file %A_ScriptDir%\mouse_slow.ps1,, Hide
Return

!2:: ; Alt+2, fast
Run, powershell  -noLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file %A_ScriptDir%\mouse_default.ps1,, Hide
Return
```

This seems to work for me, remove Hide option if you want ps screen to flash while running through hotkey.